How to add a security group to an existing RDS instance in Terraform via terraform_remote_state
I'm working with Terraform and trying to apply a security group to an existing RDS instance that is managed in a different Terraform project. My setup uses terraform_remote_state to access the state file from the other project. Specifically, I want to apply a security group for Privatelink to this RDS instance.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Using terraform_remote_state to pull in the RDS instance data from the other project.
Attempting to add a new security group to the vpc_security_group_ids list for this RDS instance.
Here’s an outline of my current code:
# Access the remote state where the RDS is defined
data "terraform_remote_state" "db_state" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = "my-remote-state-bucket"
    key    = "path/to/remote/state/file"
    region = "us-west-2"
  }
}

# Security group for Privatelink
resource "aws_security_group" "privatelink_sg" {
  name        = "privatelink-sg"
  description = "Security group for Privatelink access"
  vpc_id      = data.terraform_remote_state.db_state.outputs.vpc_id

  ingress {
    # Ingress rules here
  }

  egress {
    # Egress rules here
  }
}

# Attempting to apply the security group to the RDS instance
resource "aws_db_instance" "example" {
  identifier              = data.terraform_remote_state.db_state.outputs.db_instance_id
  vpc_security_group_ids  = concat(data.terraform_remote_state.db_state.outputs.vpc_security_group_ids, [aws_security_group.privatelink_sg.id])
  
  # Other RDS configurations
}

However, this approach results in an error because I don’t have direct control over the RDS instance as it’s managed in the other Terraform project.
Question:
How can I correctly apply this new security group to the existing RDS instance? Do I need to approach this differently, or is there a workaround for managing security groups on an RDS instance defined in another Terraform project?

Well, I think whoever is responsible for the RDS code should do what you tried. In other words, they are the ones which should use a data source or terraform remote state to attach an additional security group.

If you do it this way, the next time the other Terraform runs it will remove your added security group and set it back to whatever it was in the .tf file that manages the RDS instance. You could try adding a single rule to the existing RDS security group, using https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule but depending on how that security group is managed in the other Terraform code, that could get removed as well.
